# como colocar os valores do histograma no topo da barra

Tags: r, gráfico, histograma, lattice

Estou usando o comando histogram da biblioteca lattice em R.
Gostaria de saber como posso colocar o valor em cima das barras, valor que eu falo é a contagem do histograma.
Ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite a pergunta com exemplos de dados e do código que produziu o gráfico, por favor. Para os dados, o melhor é postar a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se `dados` for muito grande, `dput(head(dados, 20))`.

Answer (score 5):

Até onde sei, pacotes gráficos mais avançados do `R`, como `lattice` e `ggplot2`, não possuem uma maneira fácil de colocar números em cima das barras do histograma. Imagino que dê pra fazer, mas é um trabalho bastante grande, justamente para desencorajar este uso. Isto se deve ao fato de quase ninguém atualmente achar que histogramas necessitam vir acompanhados de números. Gráficos devem ser o mais limpos possível, de modo que eles, e somente eles, consigam passar toda a informação necessária ao leitor. Principalmente se o histograma tiver muitas categorias, o visual fica extremamente prejudicado se cada coluna estiver acompanhada de uma número. Se o uso de números é impreterível, a sugestão é que se use uma tabela. Fica mais elegante.

Isto posto, a função `hist` do `R`, por ter sido escrita há muito tempo, possui uma maneira fácil de adicionar números aos histogramas. Basta adicionar o argumento `labels=TRUE` à sua chamada:

```
hist(cars$speed, labels=TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]