# Valores nos eixos do gráfico no RStudio

Tags: r, plot

Olá, sou nova no R. Eu plotei os dados que eu queria, mas não apareceu valor algum.
Como resolver? São poucos dados.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados são os seguintes, plotando apenas a quarta coluna (Avg.1). [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço a quem puder me ajudar

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SO português! Para saber como fazer uma boa pergunta e facilitar os que querem ajudar, dê uma olhada nesse link [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/825/80049). Na sua pergunta falta o código que vou usou para criar a figura e parte dos dados para que possamos reproduzi-la: `dput(head(NomeDosDados, 20))`.

Comment: [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288058/43953) resolve sua questão?

Answer (score 3):

Se você estiver usando a coluna X, pode ser por ter valores muito longos,então faz uma coluna dia `19:29`, mas por definição deveria aparecer os valores e o titulo do eixo.
Tenta usar a fórmula, i.e. `y~x`

```
y<-1:9
x<-11:19
plot(y~x)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu criei uma nova coluna para os dias, mas continua sem aparecer os valores :/ dataset.novo$dia = 19:31
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(dataset.novo$dia, dataset.novo$Avg.1)